# Binomial Theorem question

Tags: geometry, binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x$ in the expansion of $$\left(1-2x^3+3x^5\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^5.$$    Answer is $154$, but how?

Comment: Hi Anish, do let me know if my edit is correct.

Comment: Something isn't right here, because as written, this is _not_ going to give a term of $ \ 154x \ $ ... (In fact, _no_ term in the expansion has such a coefficient.)

Answer (score 2):

$$(1-2x^3+3x^5)\left(1+\frac1x\right)^5=\frac{(1-2x^3+3x^5)(1+x)^5}{x^5}$$

We need the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1-2x^3+3x^5)(1+x)^5$ which is $-2\cdot\binom53+3\binom51$

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to consider, without writing out the coefficients, that $ \ (1 + x^{-1})^5 \ $ will, from the binomial theorem, produce a polynomial of the form $ \ 1 + Ax^{-1} + Bx^{-2} + Cx^{-3} + Dx^{-4} + x^{-5} \ . $  When we multiply this by $ \ 1 - 2x^3 + 3x^5 \ , $ we see that multiplication by 1 cannot produce any terms in the binomial product containing $ \ x^1 \ $ .  The *only* products that can do so are $ \ -2x^3 \ \cdot Bx^{-2} \ $ and $ \ 3x^5 \ \cdot \ Dx^{-4} \ . $

Thus, the term in the polynomial product containing $ \ x \ $ has the coefficient $ \ -2B \ + \ 3D \  . $  The binomial theorem tells us that $ B \  = \ \binom53 \cdot 1^3 \cdot 1^2 \ = \ 10 \ $ and $ D \  = \ \binom51 \cdot 1^1 \cdot 1^4 \ = \ 5 $ , agreeing with **lab bhattacharjee**'s result; the coefficient is then -5 ... This leads me to believe that there is some error in the problem statement or the edit, because no term in the expansion has a coefficient as big as 154 (as verified by WolframAlpha).